# How to stop LLVM from transforming bit-masking into a branch?

Tags: c++, llvm, compiler-optimization

For context, suppose that I'm writing a bytecode interpreter, where the instructions follow one of two formats:

```
+---+--------+------+------+----------------+
| 1 | opcode | treg | areg |     unused     |
+---+--------+------+------+----------------+
32  31       20     16     12               0

+---+--------+------+-----------------------+
| 0 | opcode | treg |          imm          |
+---+--------+------+-----------------------+
32  31       20     16                      0
```

For each *opcode*, there are two options to provide its second operand: it may either be a register or an immediate value. The selection is performed by the bit 31 of the instruction word. If the MSB is 0 — then the second operand is the contents of the register, indexed by bits [12:16] of the instruction word. If the MSB is 1 — the second operand is the bits [0:16] of the instruction itself, sign-extended to the full machine word.

The simple algorithm to retrieve this second operand would just switch between two separate parsers depending on the MSB:

```cpp
reg_t decode_arg2(uint32_t instr, reg_t const* regs) {
    if (instr & (1 << 31)) {
        return regs[(instr >> 12) & 15];
    } else {
        return (int16_t)instr;
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to use a branchless algorithm, where we load both possible values into temporary variables, and then use bit magic to choose one of them:

```cpp
reg_t decode_arg2_branchless(uint32_t instr, reg_t const* regs) {
    reg_t mask = (int32_t)instr >> 31;
    reg_t reg = regs[(instr >> 12) & 15];
    reg_t imm = (int16_t)instr;
    return (reg & mask) | (imm & ~mask);
}
```

After compiling both functions with GCC and comparing their performance in an artificial stress test, the branchless version came out to be about 2.5x faster than the branching one. So, based on this observation, it seems reasonable to want the bit magic to stay in the final implementation.

However, when we compile the same code with Clang, it tries to be clever with the branchless version — it correctly detects that both functions do essentially the same thing, but then this same knowledge makes it emit code with full branches for both cases. On Godbolt, [using Clang 16.0.0 with `-O2`](https://godbolt.org/z/63q8jj5Mj) produces this assembly:

```
decode_arg2(unsigned int, long const*):
        test    edi, edi
        js      .LBB0_1
        movsx   rax, di
        ret
.LBB0_1:
        shr     edi, 12
        and     edi, 15
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rsi + 8*rdi]
        ret
decode_arg2_branchless(unsigned int, long const*):
        test    edi, edi
        jns     .LBB1_1
        shr     edi, 12
        and     edi, 15
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rsi + 8*rdi]
        ret
.LBB1_1:
        movsx   rax, di
        ret
```

**There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to prevent Clang from doing this, so this is where the main question arises: how do you prevent Clang from transforming the bit-masking into a full branch?**

---

Some tidbits that I found so far by myself:

- On Godbolt, you can see each optimization pass in detail in the "LLVM Opt Pipeline" window. Using this, we can see that:

  1. Initially, the `InstCombinePass` detects the masking pattern that we use and replaces it with a `select` intrinsic (corresponding to the trinary operator).
  2. Then, the `X86 DAG->DAG Instruction Selection` changes the `select` into `CMOV`. That's not what we originally wrote, but should probably be still fine.
  3. Finally, `X86 cmov Conversion`, for some reason, decides that `CMOV` is not actually a good fit in this case, and expands it into a true branch.

  So, if we could disable one of these passes, the problem should be solved. However, I didn't find an official way to disable specific optimization passes. Even if there is one, I would like it to be applicable on a scale of individual functions (so that they would still work in other places, where they are more likely to be beneficial), and "survive" through the whole-program optimization during the link phase.
- Some sources suggested marking the branch condition with `__builtin_unpredictable`, to discourage the `X86 cmov Conversion` from expanding the selection. Since there are no actual branches in the source code to begin with, I'm not even sure where to put it. Hanging it onto the `mask`'s value seems to have no effect.
- It is indeed possible to just hard-code the function body into inline asm, but I consider it as a last resort, to be used only if there is no other way to make LLVM emit the code I wanted.
- If you replace bitwise operations with arithmetic, like so:

  ```cpp
  reg_t decode_arg2_interp(uint32_t instr, reg_t const* regs) {
      reg_t t = instr >> 31;
      reg_t reg = regs[(instr >> 12) & 15];
      reg_t imm = (int16_t)instr;
      return reg * t + imm * (1 - t);
  }
  ```

  It's still about 15% slower than the bitwise version (again, tested with GCC), but it's now obfuscated enough for LLVM to translate the code as-is, using actual `imul` and `add` for the "interpolation". So, this approach could be used as the next best thing after inline asm. Still, there's that 15% slowdown, and that's on my specific CPU (so it might get worse on others); and there's also a slight possibility that a future version of LLVM will start detecting this pattern too.

---

In case you want to test the performance yourself, here is the source code that I use for that:

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Random {
    uint64_t state = 0x4d595df4d0f33173u;
    static constexpr uint64_t multiplier = 6364136223846793005u;
    static constexpr uint64_t increment = 1442695040888963407u;

    static uint32_t rotr32(uint32_t x, unsigned r) {
        return x >> r | x << ((32 - r) & 31);
    }

    void uniform(uint32_t& r) {
        uint64_t x = state;
        unsigned count = (unsigned)(x >> 59);
        state = x * multiplier + increment;
        x ^= x >> 18;
        r = rotr32((uint32_t)(x >> 27), count);
    }

    void uniform(uint64_t& r) {
        uint32_t q1, q2;
        uniform(q1);
        uniform(q2);
        r = (((uint64_t)q1) << 32) | q2;
    }

    void uniform(int64_t& r) {
        uint64_t q;
        uniform(q);
        r = (int64_t)q;
    }
};

using reg_t = int64_t;

__attribute__((noinline))
reg_t decode(uint32_t instr, reg_t const* regs)
{
#if defined(BRANCH)
    if (instr & 0x80000000) {
        return regs[(instr >> 18) & 0xf];
    } else {
        return (int16_t)instr;
    }
#elif defined(MUL)
    reg_t t = instr >> 31;
    reg_t reg = regs[(instr >> 18) & 0xf];
    reg_t imm = (int16_t)instr;
    return reg * t + imm * (1 - t);
#elif defined(ARR)
    reg_t reg = regs[(instr >> 18) & 0xf];
    reg_t imm = (int16_t)instr;
    reg_t arr[2] = {imm, reg};
    return arr[instr >> 31];
#elif defined(BIT)
    reg_t mask = ((int32_t)instr >> 31);
    reg_t reg = regs[(instr >> 18) & 0xf];
    reg_t imm = (int16_t)instr;
    return (reg & mask) | (imm & ~mask);
#elif defined(BIT_ATOMIC_STD)
    auto aregs =
        reinterpret_cast<std::atomic<reg_t> const*>(regs);
    reg_t mask = ((int32_t)instr >> 31);
    reg_t reg = aregs[(instr >> 18) & 0xf].load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    reg_t imm = (int16_t)instr;
    return (reg & mask) | (imm & ~mask);
#elif defined(BIT_ATOMIC_INTRIN)
    reg_t mask = ((int32_t)instr >> 31);
    reg_t reg = __atomic_load_n(
        regs + ((instr >> 18) & 0xf),
        __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    reg_t imm = (int16_t)instr;
    return (reg & mask) | (imm & ~mask);
#else
    static_assert(false, "no variant chosen");
#endif
}

volatile reg_t sink;

int main() {
    Random random;
    reg_t regs[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        random.uniform(regs[i]);
    }
    for (size_t counter = 0; counter < 10000000000; ++counter) {
        uint32_t instr;
        random.uniform(instr);
        sink = decode(instr, regs);
    }
}
```

Compile it with `g++ -DBRANCH decode.cpp -o decode_branch -O2` (replacing `-DBRANCH` with the appropriate variant) and run with `time ./decode_branch`. Do note that, to get the actual `-DBIT` version, you need to use GCC specifically — since, this being the very subject of this question, Clang (LLVM) replaces it during optimization with an equivalent of `-DBRANCH`.

Comment: Possibly related: Linus (of Linux fame) ranting about CMOV not being a good idea sometime: https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/cmov.html

Comment: @MikeVine it's a bit outdated, `cmov` is really cheap now (single cycle, more than 1 per cycle throughput), but it's still true that a branch can make one side "go away" and `cmov` by design does not

Comment: Since this is a virtual machine, all the virtual registers will almost certainly be present in the L1 cache, so there's not much to remove even on a correctly predicted branch.

Again, using the same GCC test, and biasing the instruction word's MSB by taking a bitwise and of multiple bits of the PRNG's output — it takes a bias of about 1-to-7 for the branching version to get even remotely close to the branchless one. And even when I set it to be the `imm` variant 100% of the time (skipping the memory load), the difference is less than 5%.

Comment: (cont) So, I'm pretty sure that, in this particular scenario, the branchless version is the way to go.

Also, what might be important, GCC doesn't actually emit a `cmov` in the branchless version, it instead follows the bitwise operations pretty closely.

Comment: This is a pretty weird workaround, but using a relaxed atomic load works, since atomic loads on x86 are just regular loads but compilers don't mess with them. See [here on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jb8PfeKsK)

Comment: @Delfigamer note that predicting branches is mainly used for CPU speculative execution _not_ memory access so will still be very useful for speed. However I don't think this is likely an issue anyway.

Comment: I don't know if this can help you, but it seems this is the function in the inst-combine pass that performs the transform: https://llvm.org/doxygen/InstructionCombining_8cpp_source.html#l01005

Comment: How does this do:    `auto const low_word = static_cast<std::uint16_t>(instr);    reg_t const res[] = { low_word, regs[ low_word >> 12 ] };    return res[ instr >> 31 ];`?

Comment: @Red.Wave Produces an actual array on stack, which the compiler then proceeds to actually fill, and then index into. On my machine, this ends up 20% slower than the branchless. /// Also, while refactoring the testing code, I managed to accidentally make GCC compile the simple branching version into a CMOV — and it made it practically equivalent to the bit-masking one, so there's that.

Comment: @Homer512 "Atomizing" the load, for some arcane reason, makes the `X86 cmov Conversion` change its mind and leave the CMOV in place, which then survives the rest of the pipeline till the final binary. So, that's a way to influence it, I guess. It seems quite unstable to me, though, because there's no direct link between the two — there is nothing in `atomic` that actually forces a compiler to use a `cmov` after it, so, in principle, there's nothing stopping the LLVM team from "patching" this quirk in literally the next version.

Comment: I assume clang chooses the branch because the dependency chain through the `cmov` is rather long. In the end you're battling compiler optimizations; whatever solution you will come up with, there will always be the risk that the next version changes it. TBH I'm not sure why a simple `volatile` load isn't sufficient

Comment: @Homer512: I think clang ignoring `volatile` is a bug. https://godbolt.org/z/ovajP6rc8 shows clang making branchy asm that doesn't deref the `volatile reg_t const *` in some cases, even though the abstract machine always does.  `volatile` does lead GCC in the direction of using `cmov` for a `return condition ? reg : imm` ternary (instead of that clunky bitwise blend which it doesn't optimize to cmov), although it does waste some instructions.

Comment: Does using profile feedback make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach that works, doesn't depend on x86-specific behavior (e.g. cheap atomic loads), and by my estimation has a good chance of continuing to work: Add an empty `asm` statement that references the `reg` variable.

This seems to work fine and generate good, short code.

```cpp
reg_t decode_arg2(uint32_t instr, reg_t const* regs) {
    reg_t reg = regs[(instr >> 12) & 15];
    asm("" : "+r"(reg));
    reg_t imm = (int16_t)instr;
    return (int32_t) instr < 0 ? reg : imm;
}
```

Generated assembly with clang-16 `-O2`:

```
        mov     eax, edi
        shr     eax, 12
        and     eax, 15
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rsi + 8*rax]
        movsx   rax, di
        test    edi, edi
        cmovs   rax, rcx
        ret
```

As long as clang doesn't gain the ability to inspect inline asm, I think we are fine. My hypothesis on how this works (someone with better insight might correct me): The dependency chain through the memory load is very long compared to the version with branches. By adding some assembly, we prevent clang from assessing the dependency chain.

After looking at other compile targets such as RISC-V where even the code version with explicit masking creates a branch, and comparing the code with `asm volatile` vs. just `asm`, I think it is really just the assessment of the dependency chain.

Comment: Relaxed atomic loads are cheap almost everywhere, at least up to the width of a single register.  But I guess that wouldn't be the case on some 32-bit ISAs that can't fully efficiently load a pair of registers, since `reg_t` is 64-bit.  Otherwise `std::atomic_ref<reg_t>` with `std::memory_order_relaxed` is portable but should compile well with GCC/clang.  (Without C++20, if you don't mind GNU extensions,  `__atomic_load(&regs[...], __ATOMIC_RELAXED)`.  But if you're using GNU extensions, this dummy asm statement is probably better, once you fix it to require the same reg for input/output.)

Comment: `asm("" : "=r"(reg): "r"(reg));` lets the compiler use that statement as a copy, expecting the asm template to produce the output in a different register than it picked for the input.  Since you don't run any asm instructions that copy `%1` to `%0`, you can't safely describe it that way to the compiler.  Use a `"+r"(reg)` input to tell the compiler that a single register is both an input and output.  It's syntactic sugar for a matching constraint like `"0"(reg)` to force the input to pick the same place as the `%0` output.

Comment: I'm surprised `asm` (not `asm volatile`) works for this, but it does with GCC and clang https://godbolt.org/z/KTjYx375G.  Without `asm volatile`, the asm statement can be optimized away if the result is unused, like in the `imm` side of the ternary.  It does still make the compiler forget what it knows about the value, like defeating constant propagation, and requiring the compiler to materialize this C++ variable in a register if it is used further.  So I guess that happens to work.  Yeah very plausible that it defeats dep-chain analysis, if that's what clang was doing.